Azure app-service deployment center - what does the "Disconnect" do and how to "reconnect"?
I have an app-service that is hosting a FastAPI app in a container registry. The image below is the Settings page of the app-service's Deployment Center in Azure.

I clicked on it to see all the options otherwise hidden and now I can't undo it. It took about 20 seconds to process the "disconnect" command and, and although I AM deploying the app using Azure  DevOps CICD pipelines, the "Azure Repos" connection is not restored.
The documentation doesn't say much and the screenshots seem outdated. It says though that for Azure Pipelines there's nothing to configure in Azure Portal, only in Azure DevOps, which is already done, and I expected to see again the Disconnect button after the next deployment -- didn't happen.

I'm trying to understand what exactly did I do (this is a dev/test environment, by the way). I would also prefer the "Disconnect" button back, at least it indicates that a connection exists.
Edit:
@wadezhou-MSFT this is the deployment task:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: login to ACR
  inputs:
     command: login
     repository: $(acrImageName)
     containerRegistry: "$(dockerRegistryServiceConnectionDev)"
- script: |
     docker pull $(dev_docker_registry_name)/$(acrImageName):$(tag)
     docker tag $(dev_docker_registry_name)/$(acrImageName):$(tag) $(dev_docker_registry_name)/$(acrImageName):latest
     docker push $(dev_docker_registry_name)/$(acrImageName):latest
  displayName: Build and push dev image

The app-service is deployed using bicep with Azure CLI (used to be a AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task before):
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: appServiceName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appPlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    siteConfig: {
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      scmType: 'VSTSRM'
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
      appCommandLine: dockerRegistryStartupCommand
      appSettings: [
        {
           name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
           value: '1'
        }
        {
           name: 'WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE'
           value: 'true'
        }
        ...
      ]
      ...
    }
  }
}


Please show the deployment task detail in DevOps pipeline. Did you use AzureWebAppContainer@1 task?

@wadezhou-MSFT I added more details to the initial post.

I updated my answer based on your information. Can you please check if I answered you question?

In your pipeline yaml, it only logins to ACR, build image and push it to ACR, not related to the app service yet.
You are deploying web service via Azure CLI with bicep, not found any sourcecontrols in your bicep. The connection cannot be created if you rerun the pipeline as you are not deploying from pipeline. Try to deploy from pipeline to check the connection again.
Sample yaml:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: '$(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        repository: '$(imageRepository)'
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        tags: '$(tag)'

    - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'ARMConn6'
        appName: 'wadeapp3'
        containers: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'

Click view log in overview page on app service, it will direct to deployment center details, but as @VladDX mentioned, not registry settings content but repo content.

If use azure cli such as az webapp create --name Dev-App \ --plan Dev-AppServicePlan \ --resource-group chat-Dev \ --deployment-container-image-name devcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/chat-node:latest,on deployment center , it will be:


By "deploying from the pipeline" you mean using an AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment task instead of running an az script, right?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/add-template-to-azure-pipelines?tabs=CLI#use-azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-task

The task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 won't create connection on deployment center as the bicep doesn't have sourcecontrols. In you pipeline, you can use AzureWebAppContainer@1 to deploy the ACR image to app service.

@wadezhou-MSFT Bicep only creates a resource. It has nothing to do with a workload deployment. The question is about worload deployment, not ARM or Bicep.

Thanks @VladDX, that's why the task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment doesn't work and not recommended, even it has source controls(it creates external git conenction not auzre repos actually), if would like to recover from devops pipeline, task AzureWebAppContainer@1 can create the Azure repos connection, but it indeed doesn't have Registry settings , while Project ,repo, branch. If only would like disconnect back, it can do.

Thank you for the detailed explanations! I am a bit confused of why I had the Azure repos connection already in place in the current setup though (inherited code), but the rest is clear.

There are different deployment models for an App Service in Azure. They are exclusive. If you use one, you should ignore other ones.
Deployment models for an App Service:

sFTP.
Continuous deployment from a code repo.
Local Git.
Continuous deployment of a Docker image.
ZIP deploy.
Run from package.


So, if deployment is done via Azure DevOps Pipeline it usually use #5 - ZIP deploy.
In your case, you only publish Docker image via Azure DevOps pipeline. But deployment works using
"4 - Continuous deployment of a Docker image.
"Source: Azure Repos" is for #2 - Continuous deployment from a code repo.
They are mutually exclusive. You shouldn't expect Disconnect (#2) to reappear after deploying using #4 or #5.

My subjective opinion:

sFTP is an ancient solution that shouldn't be discussed. You need to manage SFTP connection. It's not atomic.

Continuous deployment from a code repo is not for Production use. It deploys every change of the code, with no tests or infrastructure provisioning.

Local Git deployment is similar to the Continuous deployment from a code repo

Continuous deployment for a Docker image is a good solution for Docker-based approach. However, you might want to consider Container Apps instead of App Services for Docker.

ZIP deploy is an acceptable model that can and should be used from a CI/CD pipeline. Most commonly used approach.

Run from package can be a better approach due to advantages. Benefits:

Atomic deploys
Faster deployment
Reduced cold start for JavaScript-based apps




Application resource shouldn't know how it is deployed. Therefore, only Docker-based, ZIP Deploy, and Run from package approaches should be utilized for Production.
Also, deployment stage should be a part of the CI/CD pipeline. Abovementioned approaches can be used in a pipeline (e.g., Azure Pipelines, GitHub Actions, etc.)

Links:

ZIP deploy - Deploy files to App Service
Local Git - Local Git deployment to Azure App Service
Continuous deployment for a Docker image - Migrate custom software to Azure App Service using a custom container
sFTP - Deploy your app to Azure App Service using FTP/S
Continuous deployment from a code repo - Continuous deployment to Azure App Service
Run from package - Run your app in Azure App Service directly from a ZIP package

